# Gxt focus management

Tags: java, javascript, gwt, focus, gxt

I am working with Gxt. I need to set focus to the first enabled field on the page. But I have a lot of pages and I want to centralize that behaviour. There is a lack of documentation in Gxt so I wonder if somebody has met such a problem and can help me.

Now it goes like that in each component's class

```
protected void resetFocus() {
    combobox.focus();
}

@Override
public void show() {
    super.show();
    resetFocus();
}
```

I have *found com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.aria.FocusManager* but is absolutely unclear how can I use it. Or maybe It is also possible to get chain of fields as they go on the component according to the focus. And I can move *resetFocus* method to the parent class.

Smth like that

```
protected void resetFocus() {
    *getFocusChain().get(0).focus();*
}
```

Comment: Maybe you can show us your code?  It doesn't make people want to help with your problem when you call it a trivial task, it makes you seem lazy in the research part of the problem.

Comment: Thanks, you are right! I realized that my post shows me not from a best side. I will rewrite it.

Comment: rewritten, open for critic and filling need of help.

Answer (score 3):

Based on the last response, I got this to work in a GXT3 window by doing the following:

```
@Override
public void show() {
    super.show();
    Scheduler.get().scheduleDeferred(new Scheduler.ScheduledCommand() {
        @Override
        public void execute() {
            field.focus();
        }
    });
}
```

This way when the window opens, the field has focus and you can begin typing.

Answer (score 2):

Focus after render some delay
So you have to use `Scheduler.get().scheduleDeferred` method. Or `DeferredCommand` on GWT 1.7 or before.

Example of usage:

```java
Scheduler.get().scheduleDeferred(new ScheduledCommand() {

    @Override
    public void execute() {
        widget.focus();
        widget.el().focus();
        widget.getElement().focus();
    }
});
```

Comment: It isn't helpful at all. I was looking for solution I can implement once and do not copy-paste focus() code. I have made my own focus management system, so the question is no more actual.

Comment: Why don't you share your solution here. Maybe your solution will help other people.

Comment: At least it worked for me. I was using scheduleFinally which doesn't work, scheduleDeferred did the trick. I used only someTextField.focus(), in GXT 3 it seems to be enough.