# How to apply some js to gxt element?

Tags: javascript, gwt, radio-button, gxt

in several browsers I have square around radio buttons. I managed to solve it using javascript: `onfocus="this.blur()"`, but my web app is build with gwt and gxt, and I don't know how to apply this to my `Radio button;`

Comment: try this in CSS: `input, input[type="radio"] {border: 0; outline: none;}`

Comment: also removing focus from element you are focusing on sounds like a wrong thing to do, especially when you want to tab thru elements

Comment: I've tried even this: input[type="radio"] {
    outline: none !important;
    border: 0px !important;
    outline-style: none !important;
} but id doesn't help. I still have a square in firefox on ubuntu

Comment: Ok, i solved it just setting focus to other element

Answer (score 1):

You can remove `focus` by passing `false` to `setFocus` method.

```
button.setFocus(false);
```

see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4087730/gxt-focus-management)

Comment: I'm using GXT radio button, not GWT.

Comment: it doesn't have set focus method ??

Comment: No, it has setBorders(); but it doesn't help

Comment: tried like this in css  .ext-gecko *:focus {
outline-style: none !important;
}??

Comment: Yes, I did, it didn't help

Comment: Sorry,Not familiar with GXT.Can't help you furthur.

Comment: But,I am sure that there is some method on widget.Check in API.Refer this it may push you furthur http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4087730/gxt-focus-management

Comment: Just curious you called .focus()..?